# How can I filter data from a large txt file with PyArrow engine and usecols parameter in Pandas read_csv?

Tags: pandas, python-3.8, pyarrow

## Problem Statement

I have a `.txt` file with 7 columns of floating point data. The data doesn't have any headers and the columns are separated by a space. The file is so large date it takes so long to read it with single thread that's why I need parallelism so I use PyArrow.

### Setup

The issue is being experienced on the following system and software configurations:

- OS: `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`
- Python version: `Python 3.8.10`
- pandas version: `2.0.1`
- pyarrow version: `12.0.0`

### File.txt

```
17.835 -1.195 -1.742 -1836 168 184 195
17.813 -1.199 -1.74 -1816 173 189 202
15.841 -1.067 -1.72 -1964 168 190 203
14.674 -1.252 -1.27 -877 78 85 92
14.499 -1.092 -1.697 -1138 96 98 103
14.482 -1.093 -1.695 -1044 97 99 104
14.461 -1.223 -1.691 -968 98 98 102
14.468 -1.221 -1.69 -845 94 94 97
14.496 -1.237 -1.693 -941 85 86 85
14.481 -1.236 -1.689 -846 81 83 83
14.481 -1.234 -1.689 -719 81 83 82
14.48 -1.222 -1.696 -1134 107 107 111
```

### Current Workaround

Here's my current (unintended) workaround:

```py
names = [str(i) for i in range(7)]
pointcloud = read_csv(
    pointcloud_file,
    index_col=None,
    dtype=np.float16,
    names=names,
    header=None,
    sep=" ",
    engine="pyarrow",
).to_numpy(dtype=np.float16)[:, :3]
```

### Desired Solution

I am looking for a solution that can filter the data while reading it as parallel as possible, considering the limitations on the main memory space.

### Initial Approach

My initial approach was to call the function as follows:

```py
names = [str(i) for i in range(7)]
pointcloud = read_csv(
    pointcloud_file,
    index_col=None,
    dtype=np.float16,
    names=names,
    header=None,
    sep=" ",
    engine="pyarrow",
    usecols=[0,1,2],
).to_numpy(dtype=np.float16)
```

### Error

However, the PyArrow engine apparently throws an error that I can't find a solution for. As a result, my current workaround is to read the entire file and then eliminate the last 3 rows. This isn't ideal due to constraints on my main memory space, so I need a solution that allows me to filter while reading.

The traceback of the error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "semantic3D_new.py", line 393, in <module> 
    Fire() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fire/core.py", line 141, in Fire 
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fire/core.py", line 475, in _Fire 
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace( 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fire/core.py", line 691, in _CallAndUpdateTrace 
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs) 
  File "semantic3D_new.py", line 379, in create_tfrecord 
    _create_tfrecord( 
  File "semantic3D_new.py", line 322, in _create_tfrecord 
    pointcloud, labels = _read_txt_file(pointcloud_file, label_file) 
  File "semantic3D_new.py", line 263, in _read_txt_file 
    pointcloud = read_csv( 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 912, in read_csv 
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 583, in _read 
    return parser.read(nrows) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1692, in read 
    df = self._engine.read()  # type: ignore[attr-defined] 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/arrow_parser_wrapper.py", line 156, in read 
    convert_options=pyarrow_csv.ConvertOptions(**self.convert_options), 
  File "pyarrow/_csv.pyx", line 825, in pyarrow._csv.ConvertOptions.__init__ 
  File "pyarrow/_csv.pyx", line 979, in pyarrow._csv.ConvertOptions.include_columns.__set__ 
  File "stringsource", line 15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string 
TypeError: expected bytes, int found
```

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues about this? I think that pandas should either support this (numeric `usecols`), or provide a better error message.

Comment: Apparently it is indeed a bug with the latest version. Here is the link https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53229